# Root object Alfresco "session.getTicket()" "sessionticket.getTicket()"

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm trying to use `session.getTicket()` to obtain the authentication ticket of alfresco. But I get

> "session is not defined"

I try too `sessionticket.getTicket()` and gives me the same error.

Any help?

Comment: Where you are trying to get this ticket and for what? Add some more details.

Comment: for /alfresco/service/api/upload @mitpatoliya

I have problems with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975107/alfresco-update-file-error-post
I don't know if I need this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working on share, you are most probably authenticated.

If it is the case, you can access your alfresco repo through the proxy endpoint in share and all requests will have authentication ticket attached to them before getting forwarded to your repo !

In other terms, use this endpoint :

```
/share/proxy/alfresco/api/upload
```

Instead of :

```
/alfresco/service/api/upload
```

and You won't even have to attach a ticket to your requests !