# Alfresco Update File - ERROR POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm trying to update a file in Alfresco... And I make this code:

```
var csrf_header = Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getHeader();
var csrf_token = Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getToken();
function getResponse(pdfbase64) {
                var fd = new FormData();
                if (Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy && Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.isFilterEnabled())
                {
                    fd.append(csrf_header, csrf_token);
                }
                fd.append("username", "admin");
                fd.append("updatenoderef", nodeRef);
                fd.append("filedata", pdfbase64);
                fd.append("majorversion", "true");
                fd.append("overwrite", "true");
                alert(fileUpdateURL);
                $.ajax({
                  url: fileUpdateURL,
                  type: "POST",
                  data: fd,
                  processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
                  contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
                });

}
```

The variable `pdfbase64` is the content to put on the file (the changes that I made on the file to update the file in base64), but maybe this isn't the right format?, `nodeRef` is the reference of the file like: `"workspace://SpacesStore/4fb1b7e7-2502-4011-8870-17e8d626b93b"` and `fileUpdateURL` is the `URL` to `POST`: `http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/api/upload`

[Source of params](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/RESTful-UploadUploadPost.html)

I got the error:

> POST http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/api/upload 500
>   Internal Server Error
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Possible CSRF attack noted when
>   comparing token in session and request  parameter. Request: POST
>   /share/proxy/alfresco/api/upload  at
>   org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.CSRFFilter$AssertTokenAction.run(CSRFFilter.java:845)
>     at
>   org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:312)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241
>   )     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.SSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SSOAuthenticationFilter.java:447)
>
> at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241
>   )     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.MTAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(MTAuthenticationFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241
>   )     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

EDIT:
If I use

> http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/upload

instead of

> http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/api/upload

I get the error:

```
{
    "status" : 
  {
    "code" : 400,
    "name" : "Bad Request",
    "description" : "Request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."
  },  

  "message" : "Required parameters are missing",  
  "exception" : "",

  "callstack" : 
  [ 

  ],

  "server" : "Community v5.0.0 (d r99759-b2) schema 8,022",
  "time" : "Jan 24, 2016 1:14:41 PM"
}
```

Can anyone help me?

EDIT2:

I try to make the request with http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/api/upload with this:

```
function getResponse(pdfbase64) {
            var csrf_header = Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getHeader();
            var csrf_token = Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getToken();
            var fd = new FormData();
            if (Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy && Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.isFilterEnabled())
            {
                fd.append(csrf_header, csrf_token);
                fileUpdateURL += "?" + Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getParameter() + "=" + encodeURIComponent(Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getToken());

            }
            fd.append("username", "admin");
            fd.append("updatenoderef", nodeRef);
            fd.append("filedata", pdfbase64);
            fd.append("majorversion", "true");
            fd.append("overwrite", "true");
            alert(fileUpdateURL);
            $.ajax({
                url: fileUpdateURL,
                type: "POST",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
                contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
            });

    }
```

But I obtain the error:

```
{
        "status" : 
      {
        "code" : 400,
        "name" : "Bad Request",
        "description" : "Request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."
      },  

      "message" : "Required parameters are missing",  
      "exception" : "",

      "callstack" : 
      [ 

      ],

      "server" : "Community v5.0.0 (d r99759-b2) schema 8,022",
      "time" : "Jan 24, 2016 1:14:41 PM"
    }
```

Comment: Is the ajax call executed in an "alfresco share" page ? What is it the url of the current page ?

Comment: Yes. localhost:8080/share/page/hdp/ws/my-page?...

Comment: @PRVS What are you trying to achieve ? are you trying to upload document from an Aikau page ? Do you really need CSRF ?

Comment: Yes. I dont know if i need but I have the three options above, that I try, and the errors.

Comment: The Aikau influence anything?

Comment: There is better/way easier ways to do this in aikau !

Comment: How? My document is "show" in Aikau page, I made the changes there... But after i want to Update the file of the respository (of alfresco)

Comment: If you can post your aikau page controller here, I might be able to help you further !

Comment: Controller? I have an action button on the files that opens a Aikau page, in that page I have only one button that makes a signature and then appears the pdf signed... After that I want to Update this pdf with the signature. Only this.

Comment: But I don't know what is "controller", i can send you what you want, if this help me and help you to understand me. But the above comment is what I want to make

Comment: The controller is the server-side js for your aikau page (localhost:8080/share/page/hdp/ws/my-page)

Comment: But i'm programming this on a applet not on the server-side js. I don't have. Can you help me on that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101620/discussion-between-younes-regaieg-and-prvs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving these lines inside your function:

```
var csrf_header = Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getHeader();
var csrf_token = Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getToken();
```

And if that does not solve your problem and the issue turn out to be not a matter of variable scope for `csrf_*` vars, then you should try hint (2) from [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/csfr-policy.html)

---

**UPDATE :**
As I explained in our chat you should replace :

```
fd.append("filedata", pdfbase64);
```

with :

```
fd.append("filedata", new Blob([pdfbase64], {type: 'application/pdf'}););
```

Comment: I put use this and the POST was made to : http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/api/upload?Alfresco-CSRFToken=32KpD2nGTt3SiBPgGJgy48iYRFZ2IUau6QC3jwcpIMg%3D

But this not works. The hint is  `if (Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy && Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.isFilterEnabled())
                {
                    fd.append(csrf_header, csrf_token);
                    fileUpdateURL += "?" + Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getParameter() + "=" + encodeURIComponent(Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getToken());

                }` this right? Not solve the problem :(

Comment: Oh @YReg: , but the error is different...
`{
    "status" : 
  {
    "code" : 400,
    "name" : "Bad Request",
    "description" : "Request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."
  },  
  
  "message" : "Required parameters are missing",  
  "exception" : "",
  
  "callstack" : 
  [ 
      
  ],
  
  "server" : "Community v5.0.0 (d r99759-b2) schema 8,022",
  "time" : "Jan 24, 2016 2:32:26 PM"
}
`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the header, pass the token on the url:

```
if (Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy && Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.isFilterEnabled())
{
   url += "?" + Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getParameter() + "=" + encodeURIComponent(Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getToken());
}
```

As described in [CSRF Policy](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/ewinlof/2013/03/11/introducing-the-new-csrf-filter-in-alfresco-share/)

> When uploading a file by submitting a form with enctype
>   multipart/form-data it is not possible to set a header on the request,
>   the reason is not because of the enctype specifically but due to the
>   fact that its not possible to set a header on any form submission in
>   the browser.

The other solution is to use Alfresco.forms.Form that takes care of everything.

Comment: I made this above but I got the error 400. See my third exemple on the answer. I made this.

Comment: 400 probably means that the url is not correct. Try to write it on the console. It could be just a typo...

Comment: Actually... the easiest way to troubleshoot is to use the dev tool in chrome or firefox. So you will see exactly what url has been called. Use F12 to open the dev tool and then open the "network" tab.

Comment: "status" : { "code" : 400, "name" : "Bad Request", "description" : "Request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect." }, "message" : "Required parameters are missing", "exception" : "",

Comment: I think that the problem is that you are using "append" that adds a parameter to the url, but then you are using the question mark that can be used only at the beginning of the query string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101535/discussion-between-prvs-and-marco-altieri).

Comment: I have to pass with "?" ? docs.alfresco.com/5.0/… here i see that have to be a html form data :S